# Laravel Elixir - Unable to use .version with css and multiple js files

Tags: version, gulp, bower, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I am having issues with Laravel Elixir `.version('xxxxxx.js')`. For some reason, it appears as though I cannot use `.version` with js files or in addition to `.css` or even have multiple versioned js files.

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    /**
     * My Less
     */

    mix.less('app.less').version('public/css/app.css');

    /**
     * Vendor Scripts
     */

    mix.scripts([
        'jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources/assets/bower_components/').version('public/js/vendor.js');

    /**
     * My Scripts
     */

    mix.scripts(['app.js','app2.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/scripts').version('public/js/vendor.js');

});
```

My laravel-elixir config is as follows:

```
var config = {
    production: !! util.env.production,
    srcDir: 'app',
    assetsDir: 'resources/assets/',
    cssOutput: 'public/css',
    jsOutput: 'public/js',
    bowerDir: 'resources/assets/bower_components',
    tasks: [],
    watchers: { default: {} },
    duplicate: [],
    concatenate: { css: [], js: [] }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same problem. It appears that `version()` overides the `build` folder at each call.

You need to call `version` only once at the end with all the files, like the following:

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    /**
     * My Less
     */

    mix.less('app.less')

    /**
     * Vendor Scripts
     */

    .scripts([
        'jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources/assets/bower_components/')

    /**
     * My Scripts
     */

    .scripts(['app.js','app2.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/scripts')

    /**
     * My Versioning
     */
    .version([
        'public/css/app.css',
        'public/js/vendor.js', // BTW you are calling version twice on this file
        'public/js/app.js'
    ])

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me when I have several vendor scripts to concatenate. It appears to be processing `.version` asynchronously, so the concatenation has not completed prior to calling .version.

Comment: Changed the answer to chain all the methods.

Answer (score 1):

There were 2 issues with my question and BeS's solution did work but created another problem when I concatenated several vendor files:

1. mix.less and mix.scripts are called asynchronously. I was thinking of it procedurally.
2. As @BeS mentioned, I need to call version once at the end.

My Solution - Combination of BeS's solution but amended to chain the methods ensuring all scripts and less etc... have been concatenated prior to calling `.version`:

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.less('app.less')
        .scripts([
           'jquery/dist/jquery.js',
           'other.js',
           'another.js'
        ], 'public/js/vendor.js','resources/assets/bower_components/')
        .scripts(['app.js','app2.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/scripts')
        .version(['public/css/app.css', 'public/js/app.js', 'public/js/vendor.js']);
});
```

Comment: So essentially it is the same thing. I always chain all the methods, so I didn't thought about concurrent execution while wanted to stay as close to your original code as possible.Cocurrent execution is an open that is problematic also in other scenarios. Glad it helped anyway.

Comment: BTW. I've corrected the answer not to confuse people that might come by.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a versioning problem and found that there is currently a [bug with elixir versioning](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7353). *(note: at the time of writing, Elixir version <= v0.14.0)*

It looks like when concatenating a lot of files (or more likely, the output file is large), then it will not get versioned with the rest of the files.

It looks like you can run `gulp version` separately and they will get versioned. If you are experiencing this issue then `gulp` or `gulp watch` will not do it.

Here is my gulp file, **vendor.js** was being compiled but not versioned. It is not even the last file being versioned:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.sass('app.scss')

    .scripts([
        'react/react-with-addons.min.js',
        'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources/assets/bower')

    .scripts(['app.js'], 'public/js/app.js', 'resources/assets/js')

    .version([
        'css/app.css',
        'js/vendor.js',
        'js/app.js'
    ]);

});
```

Running `gulp version` afterwards will version it.

#### *Update:*

*This seems to be fixed >= v0.14.2*

Comment: Still having this problem. Any other ideas?